# Relation from two Entities, advice

Tags: php, laravel, relation

i have two entity User and Job in my laravel project.

you think this is a relation One-To-One relationship or Many-To-One?

Thanks all.

Comment: Cannot be one-to-one, at least one-to-many because one job has many users, and did one user can has many jobs?

Comment: In my project a user can has one job. But more user can has the same job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It absolutely depends on what you are trying to model:

-If one user can just have one job and vice versa then One-to-one

-If one user can have more than one job but one job just one user One-to-many

-If one user can have just one job but one job more than one user One-to-many

-If one user can have many jobs and one job, many users Many-to-Many

Comment: thanks,  you have solved my problem, i have one user can have just one job, but one jobs can has many user, then it a One-To-many

Comment: I'm glad I helped you :) @palla451